# Pandas - sort, groupby, add columns to look at a moving date windows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sliding-window

I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement a moving window and create a new column with a binary value that checks a condition (Ie. Is there a `1` in the last 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, etc. for each employee). I'm good up to the point of the sort and groupby, but not quite sure how to use the date column as a sliding window, with also given that some of the dates are in a different format (Ie `"2nd Shift"`).

What I am trying to accomplish is have it look at the `'outcome'` column, and enter a 1 if there is atleast one `1` in last x day(s). But needs to be `groupby` `'employee_id'` and in correct date order to look back x days (or I suppose if it's sorted correctly, can look back x rows, which it appears the sort does do)

Here's a sample dataset

```
employee_id = ['405395']*15 + ['405399'] *15
    
time_et = ['04-03-2021 09:07 PM','04-04-2021 08:37 PM','04-05-2021 09:38 PM',
'04-10-2021 07:07 PM','04-11-2021 01:07 PM','04-12-2021 08:10 PM',
'04-06-2021 04:07 PM','04-08-2021 07:07 PM','04-09-2021 07:07 PM',
'04-13-2021 08:10 PM','04-14-2021 02:10 PM','04-14-2021 2nd Shift',
'04-17-2021 09:07 PM','04-18-2021 04:07 PM','04-19-2021 09:38 PM',
'04-03-2021 09:07 PM','04-04-2021 08:37 PM','04-05-2021 09:38 PM',
'04-06-2021 04:07 PM','04-08-2021 2nd Shift','04-08-2021 02:07 PM',
'04-10-2021 07:07 PM','04-11-2021 01:07 PM','04-12-2021 08:10 PM',
'04-13-2021 08:10 PM','04-14-2021 02:10 PM','04-16-2021 09:38 PM',
'04-17-2021 09:07 PM','04-18-2021 04:07 PM','04-19-2021 09:38 PM']

outcome =[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]

df = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':employee_id, 'time_et':time_et, 'outcome':outcome})
```

The sort_values seems to get it partially in order, so there's that issue. And I'm troubled with the groupby and then the sliding window. Which I could do by iterating, but that doesn't seem to be efficient for a large dataset.

`df = df.sort_values(['employee_id', 'time_et']).reset_index(drop=True)` appears to work

```
print(df)
   employee_id               time_et  outcome
0       405395   04-03-2021 09:07 PM        1
1       405395   04-04-2021 08:37 PM        1
2       405395   04-05-2021 09:38 PM        0
3       405395   04-06-2021 04:07 PM        0
4       405395   04-08-2021 07:07 PM        1
5       405395   04-09-2021 07:07 PM        0
6       405395   04-10-2021 07:07 PM        0
7       405395   04-11-2021 01:07 PM        0
8       405395   04-12-2021 08:10 PM        1
9       405395   04-13-2021 08:10 PM        0
10      405395   04-14-2021 02:10 PM        0
11      405395  04-14-2021 2nd Shift        1
12      405395   04-17-2021 09:07 PM        0
13      405395   04-18-2021 04:07 PM        0
14      405395   04-19-2021 09:38 PM        0
15      405399   04-03-2021 09:07 PM        1
16      405399   04-04-2021 08:37 PM        1
17      405399   04-05-2021 09:38 PM        0
18      405399   04-06-2021 04:07 PM        1
19      405399   04-08-2021 02:07 PM        0
20      405399  04-08-2021 2nd Shift        0
21      405399   04-10-2021 07:07 PM        0
22      405399   04-11-2021 01:07 PM        0
23      405399   04-12-2021 08:10 PM        0
24      405399   04-13-2021 08:10 PM        1
25      405399   04-14-2021 02:10 PM        0
26      405399   04-16-2021 09:38 PM        1
27      405399   04-17-2021 09:07 PM        1
28      405399   04-18-2021 04:07 PM        1
29      405399   04-19-2021 09:38 PM        0
```

How do I get the next set of columns to get something like this?

**NOTE SEE MY ATTEMPT AT END: I NEARLY HAVE IT**

```
print(df.to_string())
   employee_id               time_et  outcome  1_day  2_day  3_day  4_day  5_day
0       405395   04-03-2021 09:07 PM        1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1       405395   04-04-2021 08:37 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2       405395   04-05-2021 09:38 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
3       405395   04-06-2021 04:07 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
4       405395   04-08-2021 07:07 PM        1    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
5       405395   04-09-2021 07:07 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
6       405395   04-10-2021 07:07 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
7       405395   04-11-2021 01:07 PM        0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
8       405395   04-12-2021 08:10 PM        1    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
9       405395   04-13-2021 08:10 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
10      405395   04-14-2021 02:10 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
11      405395  04-14-2021 2nd Shift        1    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
12      405395   04-17-2021 09:07 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
13      405395   04-18-2021 04:07 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
14      405395   04-19-2021 09:38 PM        0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
15      405399   04-03-2021 09:07 PM        1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
16      405399   04-04-2021 08:37 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
17      405399   04-05-2021 09:38 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
18      405399   04-06-2021 04:07 PM        1    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
19      405399   04-08-2021 02:07 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
20      405399  04-08-2021 2nd Shift        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
21      405399   04-10-2021 07:07 PM        0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
22      405399   04-11-2021 01:07 PM        0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
23      405399   04-12-2021 08:10 PM        0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
24      405399   04-13-2021 08:10 PM        1    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0
25      405399   04-14-2021 02:10 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
26      405399   04-16-2021 09:38 PM        1    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
27      405399   04-17-2021 09:07 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
28      405399   04-18-2021 04:07 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
29      405399   04-19-2021 09:38 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
```

**My Attempt:** This almost gets it, except the first row of each `employee_id` is not null. So how would I get those to be null?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':employee_id, 'time_et':time_et, 'outcome':outcome})
df = df.sort_values(['employee_id','time_et']).reset_index(drop=True)

df['bool'] = df['outcome'].map({0: False, 1: True})

for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    df['%s_day' %x] = (df.groupby('employee_id')['bool'].rolling(x, min_periods=x).sum().shift(1).astype(bool).reset_index(0, drop=True))    
    df['%s_day' %x] = df['%s_day' %x].map({False: 0, True: 1})
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why `2_day`...`5_day` for employee_id `405395` would be `1` on row # 1? shouldn't it be null

Comment: Ask yourself, "Is there at least one `1` in the last 2 days (previous 2 rows)? The answer is yes. Doesn't matter if there's a record for 2 or more days ago.

Comment: It's not looking at 2 days ago exclusively. It's looking at the last 2 day window (so 1 day and 2 day ago). Does that make sense?

Comment: @HaleemurAli, I suppose if you can do the logic that does make it exclusive (Ie there would be a null), I could probably work with that as well.

Comment: it is starting to. thanks for the explanation. however, if its looking at the last 2 day window, is it 48 hours exactly, or comparison on date value. how does the 2nd shift factor in. example: `04-06-2021 04:07 PM` is earlier than `04-08-2021 07:07 PM` by `2 days & 3 hours`

Comment: Ah good point. I didn’t think of that. I suppose a better way is not last necessarily last 2 days, but rather last 2 instances/rows (shifts)...because you’re right, there could be 2 shifts in 1 day. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: for the row where `employee_id, time_et = (405395, 04-17-2021 09:07 PM)`, i think your sample output is wrong, since the latest prior row has time `04-14-2021 2nd Shift` (3 days ago). so `1_day` & `2_day` should be `null` if i understand the logic here.

Comment: I guess that also makes sense if you're looking at the window by row rather than time.

Comment: @HaleemurAli, no the only nulls would be the first row for each employee_id (since there are no prior rows). The rest, I need binary (`1` for yes there was atleast one `1` in last x rows for that employee_id, or `0`, there was not

Answer (score 1):

to work with rolling timeframes, first set `df.index` to the time value so we can order the dataframe appropriately.

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(
  df.time_et.str.replace('2nd Shift', '11:59 PM', regex=False).rename('idx')
)
df = df.sort_values(['employee_id', 'idx'])
```

then assign the other columns in a loop using rolling & groupby.

the pertinent `rolling` arguments are

1. window: an integer specifies the number of number of rows to look back for the window start
2. closed: used to specify whether the the window ends are included (in your case, the current row is excluded)
3. min_periods: the minimum size of the window required for a calculation to yield values. this defaults to the `window` value, so we have to set it manually.

```py
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
  df[f'{i}_day'] = df.groupby('employee_id').rolling(
    window=i,
    min_periods=1,
    closed='left'
  ).outcome.max().values
```

this yields the following dataframe & you can drop the index, now that the rolling calculation is performed.

```
                    employee_id               time_et  outcome  1_day  2_day  3_day  4_day  5_day
idx
2021-04-03 21:07:00      405395   04-03-2021 09:07 PM        1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2021-04-04 20:37:00      405395   04-04-2021 08:37 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-05 21:38:00      405395   04-05-2021 09:38 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-06 16:07:00      405395   04-06-2021 04:07 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-08 19:07:00      405395   04-08-2021 07:07 PM        1    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-09 19:07:00      405395   04-09-2021 07:07 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-10 19:07:00      405395   04-10-2021 07:07 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-11 13:07:00      405395   04-11-2021 01:07 PM        0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-12 20:10:00      405395   04-12-2021 08:10 PM        1    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-13 20:10:00      405395   04-13-2021 08:10 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-14 14:10:00      405395   04-14-2021 02:10 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-14 23:59:00      405395  04-14-2021 2nd Shift        1    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-17 21:07:00      405395   04-17-2021 09:07 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-18 16:07:00      405395   04-18-2021 04:07 PM        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-19 21:38:00      405395   04-19-2021 09:38 PM        0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-03 21:07:00      405399   04-03-2021 09:07 PM        1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2021-04-04 20:37:00      405399   04-04-2021 08:37 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-05 21:38:00      405399   04-05-2021 09:38 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-06 16:07:00      405399   04-06-2021 04:07 PM        1    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-08 14:07:00      405399   04-08-2021 02:07 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-08 23:59:00      405399  04-08-2021 2nd Shift        0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-10 19:07:00      405399   04-10-2021 07:07 PM        0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-11 13:07:00      405399   04-11-2021 01:07 PM        0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-12 20:10:00      405399   04-12-2021 08:10 PM        0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0
2021-04-13 20:10:00      405399   04-13-2021 08:10 PM        1    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2021-04-14 14:10:00      405399   04-14-2021 02:10 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-16 21:38:00      405399   04-16-2021 09:38 PM        1    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-17 21:07:00      405399   04-17-2021 09:07 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-18 16:07:00      405399   04-18-2021 04:07 PM        1    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2021-04-19 21:38:00      405399   04-19-2021 09:38 PM        0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
```

Comment: ah ya! I could have just string replaced `"2nd Shift"` with `"11:59 PM"`. That was a n easy fix. Don't why I didn't think of that. Also thanks for the explanations. I was playing with `.rolling()`. I wasn't aware of the `closed` parameter